Error 415 when trying to merge PDFs by stirlingpdf.io with python
I am trying to merge two PDF files through the API of StirlingPDF with Python.
Unfortunately, I always get an Error 415 back from the request (see below).
filepaths = [r"C:\Users\Public\Documents\data1.pdf",
             r"C:\Users\Public\Documents\data2.pdf"]

binary_data=[]
for filepath in filepaths:
    # read files in binary
    with open(filepath, 'rb') as file:
        binary_data.append(file.read())

    
url = "https://stirlingpdf.io/api/v1/general/merge-pdfs"

req_data ={"fileInput": binary_data, "sortType": "orderProvided", "removeCertSign": False}

# send a POST-request to API
response = requests.post(url, data=req_data)

I already tried the easiest get methods (get uptime) and they worked.
As the documentation tells (API) i try to put it as a binary file to the API.
It should also be executed by the web-API, because the same code structure will be used in Python and VBA.
26.11.2024: The status of the webrequest is 415 'Unsupported Media Type' with the message "Content-Type 'application/json' is not supported."

files=req_data should be used instead of data

Or json=req_data.

If I use files=req_data I get an UnicodeDecodeError.
If I use json=req_data I get an InvalidJSONError.
If i try json.dumps for json=json.dumps(req_data) the I get an TypeError (Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable), because the files have to be in type binary.
